# Port 111/tcp open and rpcbind running on NFS server but invisible on NFS client

Tags: nfs

I am setting up an NFS sevrer on ubuntu 12.04 LTS server.

Running

```
nmap SERVER-IP
```

on the sever gives me:

```
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
111/tcp  open  rpcbind
2049/tcp open  nfs
```

which seems to indicate the NFS server runs

But on the client, doing the same gives me

```
   PORT     STATE    SERVICE
   22/tcp   open     ssh
   5631/tcp filtered pcanywheredata
```

The firewall (ufw) is disabled on the server and client.

Because of this I can't mount my exported folders on the client.

Any idea what prevents my client from seeing port 111 open?

Comment: Is it possible you have a router/gateway between the machine doing the scanning and the server which has this port open? run `traceroute SERVER-IP` and, if the list is short, try scanning each machine. That could get time consuming though

Comment: From the server, use `netstat` instead of `nmap`, since it will show what address each thing is listening on. Output of these commands will be useful: server: `sudo netstat -utlnp`; client: `sudo nmap -v --reason -p 111,2049 $server`; client: `rpcinfo -p $server`

Answer (score 1):

You are allowing all incoming packets to the localhost interface but not on other interfaces.

Therefore you can see the open port locally but not from another machine.

You have to allow all incoming packets to port 111 like this:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 111 -j ACCEPT
```

This will explain [iptables](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Network/IPTables) really well.

Comment: Note that port 111 traffic is not encrypted so you probably do not want to open that port for the whole world.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the nfs client also depends on `rpcbind`. However, You can stop it being running but it is recommended to run it on a nfs client also, as `rpcbind` involves username <--> userID mapping between nfs-server and nfs-client.