# Is it possible for someone to explain / let me know why this machine has rpcbind enabled? Do I need it?

Tags: rpc

```
root@SRV-1 ~ #rpcinfo
program version netid     address                service    owner
100000    4    tcp6      ::.0.111               portmapper superuser
100000    3    tcp6      ::.0.111               portmapper superuser
100000    4    udp6      ::.0.111               portmapper superuser
100000    3    udp6      ::.0.111               portmapper superuser
100000    4    tcp       0.0.0.0.0.111          portmapper superuser
100000    3    tcp       0.0.0.0.0.111          portmapper superuser
100000    2    tcp       0.0.0.0.0.111          portmapper superuser
100000    4    udp       0.0.0.0.0.111          portmapper superuser
100000    3    udp       0.0.0.0.0.111          portmapper superuser
100000    2    udp       0.0.0.0.0.111          portmapper superuser
100000    4    local     /run/rpcbind.sock      portmapper superuser
100000    3    local     /run/rpcbind.sock      portmapper superuser
100024    1    udp       0.0.0.0.143.107        status     104
100024    1    tcp       0.0.0.0.214.139        status     104
100024    1    udp6      ::.149.156             status     104
100024    1    tcp6      ::.172.200             status     104
100021    1    udp       0.0.0.0.230.243        nlockmgr   superuser
100021    3    udp       0.0.0.0.230.243        nlockmgr   superuser
100021    4    udp       0.0.0.0.230.243        nlockmgr   superuser
100021    1    tcp       0.0.0.0.151.169        nlockmgr   superuser
100021    3    tcp       0.0.0.0.151.169        nlockmgr   superuser
100021    4    tcp       0.0.0.0.151.169        nlockmgr   superuser
100021    1    udp6      ::.217.125             nlockmgr   superuser
100021    3    udp6      ::.217.125             nlockmgr   superuser
100021    4    udp6      ::.217.125             nlockmgr   superuser
100021    1    tcp6      ::.190.212             nlockmgr   superuser
100021    3    tcp6      ::.190.212             nlockmgr   superuser
100021    4    tcp6      ::.190.212             nlockmgr   superuser
```

Update: Server has active NFS Connection....

Comment: Sounds like a case of *"If it's not broken, don't fix it."* I guess I would unbind it and see if anything breaks. First though I would scour the internet to find out what `rpcbind` does and what programs might depend on it.

Comment: Its not as easy as you say it mate, I already thought of doing that. But if I indeed break something (i will since NFS is working) will mean downtime that I cannot afford.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/307483/port-111-tcp-open-and-rpcbind-running-on-nfs-server-but-invisible-on-nfs-client